# caffe custom Euclidean layer

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, euclidean-distance

I need to do a rather simple thing using the caffe framework. I want to create a new custom c++ Euclidean layer. This layer should set all values of the bottom[1]  BLOB (ground truth data) to the corresponding value of bottom[0] BLOB when this corresponding value is below a specific value.  The L2 loss will then be calculated between this modified bottom[1] and bottom[0]. The backward_cpu() will likewise need to be modified.

This can be easily done in Matlab/Python by finding the indices of bottom[0] below this threshold value. But how to efficiently code this in c++ using the BLOB's of the caffe framework is beyond me, especially since I'll also be requiring a GPU implementation. I could sequentially iterate through all elements of the BLOB but that would be inefficient. Could I cast the BLOB data into a vector<> which is more efficiently handled under c++?

For example, regarding the cpu_forward code:

```
template <typename Dtype>
void EuclideanLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>&   bottom,
const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
int count = bottom[0]->count();
threshold = 60;
caffe_sub(
  count,
  bottom[0]->cpu_data(),
  bottom[1]->cpu_data(),
  diff_.mutable_cpu_data());
float* data = blob->mutable_cpu_data();
for (int i =0; i < count; i++) {
  if data[1][i] < threshold {
    data[1][i] = data[0][i];
  }
}
Dtype dot = caffe_cpu_dot(count, diff_.cpu_data(), diff_.cpu_data());
Dtype loss = dot / bottom[0]->num() / Dtype(2);
top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = loss;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand how the following lines calculate the Euclidean cost S=∑i=(yi−h(xi))^2 in order to alter the code:

```
Dtype dot = caffe_cpu_dot(count, diff_.cpu_data(), diff_.cpu_data());
Dtype loss = dot / bottom[0]->num() / Dtype(2);
top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = loss;
```

I would like the dot product to now be calculated between the altered bottom[1] and bottom[0]. Any suggestions?